# Moving to previous element in the Collection

Tags: java, jsp, collections, struts

I have a Collection object returned from the DB. I want to see if there size is 0 or >0 and direct my forward accordingly.
To accomplish that I used iterator and `hasNext()` like below,

```
if (!report.getFtRecords().iterator().hasNext())                    
{
    NoRecord = true;
}   
if (NoRecord)
    forwardName = "successNoRecord"; // retains in the same page
else
    forwardName = "success"; //goes to 2nd page page
```

In the JSP I use the same report object and in scriptlet they are performing `iterator.hasNext()`. This works fine for '0' records returned from DB and more than 1 record returned from DB.

However if there is only one record, I use the same report object and since I do `hasNext()` in action class and do the same in JSP, Cursor moves out of the 1st record and displays nothing in the JSP (since the resultset has 1 record). Since it's an iterator I cannot reset the collection. I cannot get the size() of the collection too since my class extends abstract collection, so anything that calls `.size()` throws exception.

How do I handle the same? I tried to handle in the DB by sending the last column with the count but will end up having the same issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't check the size of the collection object directly.

Comment: As I mentioned my collection extends AbstractCollection and size is overridden as follows:public int size()
 {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); //no way to know
 }

Comment: use `for-each` loop and set it to `NoRecord=false` in the loop and break it. Now based on `NoRecord` value redirect it after the loop.

Comment: I don't see why hasNext() should move you to the next item in the collection. You should be free to call hasNext() more than once, it's next() that moves the iterator on.

Comment: @Braj...for-each still loops over the size and it throws exception. @ Si Kelly it does and displays no record. If I remove the hasNext() in action class it displays the single record in the JSP

Answer (score 0):

Does toArray() also returns UnsupportedOperationException?

> report.getFtRecords().toArray()?

You can 1) use the array to iterate, 2) check the length of the array and perform accurately.

Comment: any operation on size will call the overriden method and throws the exception.

Comment: does that includes report.getFtRecords().toArray().length ?

Comment: toArray().length internally calls size() and throws the same exception

Comment: @JNPW That makes no sense; `length` is a field for array objects and no methods need to be called to retrieve its value. Unless you're saying `toArray()` requires `size()`...

Comment: I concur. lenght is a "public final int length" field on the array.

Comment: [6/3/14 14:28:19:227 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[6/3/14 14:28:19:227 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R  at com.jdbc.QueryCollection.size(QueryCollection.java:47)
[6/3/14 14:28:19:227 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R  at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:300)
[6/3/14 14:28:19:228 EDT] 00000034 SystemErr     R  at com.abcAction.execute(abcSearchAction.java:82)

Comment: @JNPW Then the issue is with `toArray()` and not with `length`.